# How to delete from TFS all files that are deleted from working copy?

Tags: version-control, tfs

I've manually deleted some files/folders in my workspace. How do I pend deletes for those items in my TFS workspace and get those deletes to be reflected in the repository (via command line or programmatic API).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to use the `tfpt online /deletes` command from the [Team Foundation Server Power Tools](http://aka.ms/tfpt). It will prompt you to "promote" any untracked local changes that not in the Server Workspace.

Comment: The /delete detects 3 deleted folders in my case, but when I try to pend the changes, it says "One or more children have pending changes".  But its hard to see thoses pending changes if I don't have the files.  Isn't there any way to have it pick up all the deleted files and folders and just mark them as deleted?  (These files were deleted from NetBeans IDE, which is why it was not deleted from source explorer or visual studio...)

Answer (score 5):

Deleting items within your working folders will not reflect the delete within source control. To delete the items from source control do the following:

1. Delete it from source control ui, do this by right clicking the item and deleting then committing the change.
2. Open VS Command line and run the tf properties command, example: `tf properties /s:TFSServerCollection "$/FilePath/Filename.jpg"` 
   This will let you retrieve the delete ID, for this example lets say the delete id 12345
3. In the same VS Command line window, run tf destroy command, example: `tf destroy /s:TFSServerCollection "$/FilePath/Filename.jpg";x12345`

Don't forget to add the 'x' before the delete ID. Press enter and it will prompt you if you want to delete the item. Say yes, and then press enter. Just be careful as tf destroy complete removed the item and/or folder from source control including it's history.

Comment: I voted this up because it's a good description of the process for **permanently destroying** unwanted files, but wanted to reinforce Frankie C's last sentence. In most cases under source control, destroy is dangerous overkill when a simple delete is desired.

Comment: I was running this command with /preview option but it was saying either it couldn't find the item or I didn't had access. Then I tried after removing the deletion id with /preview option. It displayed the message item was destroyed and it had attached deletion id to the name. There I noticed X in the deletion id. Then I appended with deletion id with X as the prefix to the item name and ran the command with /preview option. Now it showed item destroyed message. I realized my mistake of not adding X. I used VS 2017 Command Prompt. I think in this version deletion id might not be required.

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio 2012: These deletions will be detected, but listed in the "Excluded Changes" section. Open this list and click to "promote" the changes.

Comment: however, I had "added" files to the project, then manually deleted them before they were checked in the first time.. these had to be manually deleted from the TFS source explorer

Answer (score 0):

Deleted Files can be checked-in like regular changes, however - if you use Solution-Explorer to checkin, deleted files aren't included (because only files which are STILL in the solution are included in the changeset).

I ALWAYS do my checkins via the source-control-explorer - then deleted files are also included in the checkin (if those deleted files are below the source-control-folder you are checkin in)

Greetings
Johannes

P.S.: if you delete the files via windows-file explorer, they aren't marked as "deleted" in your working copy. ALWAYS use VS2010 to delete files (or alternatively the shell extension included in TFS Server-Powertools)

Comment: Problem is you *can't* always do that. In my case, a 3rd party tool makes the changes to the folder. It has no clue I'm using TFS.